# wait on a variable to execute condition on a php mail function

Tags: php, email

I'm facing a case where i have a php page that sends a few variables results to an email address, which works perfect, but now before sending email i need to wait on a variable and then execute email. the group of varibales lets call it D group and the 2 variables Z group

A how to makle this variable reach at the same php page while the firsts variable awaits.

B it must be awaiting for 2 hours only if the variable does not reach it must send the email, besides this if the user subrmit D group before the 2 hours let this rewrite and set hours back to 0 and wait for Z group again.

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-06-27 08:00:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
//echo $interval->format('%h');
if ($interval->format('%h') > 2 ) {
echo "yes more than 2 hours";
 } else {
 echo "not more than 2 hours";
// 12 hours are up
// give your error message
}
?>
```

was thinking on time interval to get the 2 hours diferent then create another if condition comparing if the other variable existe so this is what i came up with.

```
 <?php
$groupD = $_GET["info"];
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-06-27 08:00:00');
sleep(1800);  // sleep for 30 mins awaiting
$groupz = $_GET["infoxx"];
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
//echo $interval->format('%h');


if ($interval->format('%h') > 2 ) {
if (!is_null($groupD) & !is_null($groupz)){
    echo "execute mail";
}
else {
    echo "wont execute";
}

} else {
 echo "not more than 2 hours";
// 12 hours are up
 // give your error message
}
```

?>

this issue im facing is how to keep group D waitng until group Z arrive on same php page, i set sleep 30 mns because 2 hours is maximun should wait on variable, how ever its a test.

and here is my mail script ///(the variables i receive are coming from some js script via ajax in an array)

```
>?php 
 $mail = $_GET["info"];
    //sleep(60);
    foreach ($mail as $gtm) {
   $message .= $gtm;
    }
    $header ="From: no-reply@test.com" . "\r\n";
    $para    = 'web2@test.com';
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $titulo  = 'Mailing list Newsletter';

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<br/> <p>El siguiente usuario abandono el la compra de un paquete en booking hello </p><br/>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="2">';
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" .  $mail[0] ."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Precio Total del paquete:</strong> </td><td>" .  $mail[1] ."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Nombre:</strong> </td><td>" .  $mail[2] ."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Apellido:</strong> </td><td>" .  $mail[3] ."</td></tr>";

    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";



       if(mail($para, $titulo, $message, $header)){
                die();
        }else{
        //echo "false";
       }

      /*    }else{
        echo "false";
        }


     */

      }
   ?>
```

Comment: The page is already loaded with GET values at php execution as these values are in the URL, if you change them it should execute the code from the begining...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward approach would be the file that needs to reach a particular page **first** should write to some tmp file -- `arrived.txt`

The file that needs to wait is polling (i.e. every 5 seconds, up to two hours) to see if the file `arrived.txt` is EMPTY or NOT --- regardless of the content in it.

- If it is not empty then: empty the file and `DO ACTION X`
- If it is empty then: `DO ACTION Y`

**EDIT**

Here's how to write to file:

```
$file = 'temp.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "Arrived");
```

Here's how to check if file is empty or not:

```
if(filesize($filename) > 0) {
    //file not empty...
    //DO ACTION X
} else {
    //file is empty...
    //DO ACTION Y
}
```

Here's how to *poll* every 5 seconds

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 120; $i++) {
    if(filesize($filename) > 0) {
        //file not empty...
        //DO ACTION X
    } else {
        //file is empty...
        //DO ACTION Y
    }
    sleep(5); //wait 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: i´m not that familiar with how to do this on a txt file

Comment: @walteralexander, added the code bits to get you going.

Comment: im gonna edit the question so you can see my php mail script and help me on where to paste my code